# Merge the current line with the line above in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I have a pretty long list, like so:

```
itemOne
itemTwo
,itemThree
itemFour
itemFive
,itemSix
,itemSeven
```

Each line that starts with a comma needs to be merged with the line above, like so:

```
itemOne
itemTwo,itemThree
itemFour
itemFive,itemSix,itemSeven
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with:

```
:%s/\n,/,/g
```

Answer (score 4):

An efficient way is to use the following `:global` command:

```
:g/^,/-j!
```

Comment: I greatly prefer this method over generic :subst because it is so much more expressive and leverarges 'normal' (no pun intended) commands that you'd use manually as well. No need to dabble with esoteric escapes, `\r` versus `\n` etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this substitution:

```
:%s#\n\ze,##
```

Explanation:

- `%s#` begin a substitution on all lines.
- `\n` match the newline character.
- `\ze,` set the end of the match before the comma so the comma will not be replaced.
- `##` replace with nothing (to remove the newline character).